# Pandas crosstab - How to print rows/columns for values that don't exist in the data sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, crosstab, reindex

I am a beginner with pandas at best and I couldn't find a solution to this problem anywhere.

Let's say I have two variables: variable1, variable2.

They can have the following **predefined** values:

```
variable1 = ['1', '4', '9', '15', '20']
variable2 = ['2', '5', '6']
```

However, the current data set only has some of those values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({variable1 : ['1', '9', '20'],
                  variable2 : ['2', '2', '6']})
```

When crossing the variables:

```
pd.crosstab(df.variable1, df.variable2)
```

I get:

```
variable2  2  6
variable1      
1          1  0
20         0  1
9          1  0
```

Is there a way to put all the possible categorical values in both the columns and the rows even if the current data set does not have all of them? The goal is to have a table of the same size when running the script with an updated data set which may have the values that were not present in the previous data set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
variable1 = ['1', '4', '9', '15', '20']
variable2 = ['2', '5', '6']


df = pd.DataFrame({'variable1' : ['1', '9', '20'],
                  'variable2' : ['2', '2', '6']})

print (df)                  
  variable1 variable2
0         1         2
1         9         2
2        20         6

df = pd.crosstab(df.variable1, df.variable2)
df = df.reindex(index=variable1, columns=variable2, fill_value=0)
print (df)
variable2  2  5  6
variable1         
1          1  0  0
4          0  0  0
9          1  0  0
15         0  0  0
20         0  0  1
```

---

```
from collections import OrderedDict


valuelabels = OrderedDict([('S8', [['1', 'Medical oncology'], 
                                   ['2', 'Hematology'], 
                                   ['3', 'Hematology/Oncology'], 
                                   ['4', 'Other']]), 
                           ('S9', [['1', 'Academic / Teaching Hospital'], 
                                   ['2', 'Community-Based Solo Private Practice'], 
                                   ['3', 'Community-Based Group Private Practice (record practice size )'], ['4', 'Community Non-Teaching Hospital'], 
                                   ['5', 'Comprehensive Cancer Center'], 
                                   ['6', 'Other (specify)']])])
#print (valuelabels)


df = pd.DataFrame({'variable1' : ['1', '2', '4'],
                  'variable2' : ['2', '3', '1']})

table = pd.crosstab(df.variable1, df.variable2)      
print (table)
variable2  1  2  3
variable1         
1          0  1  0
2          0  0  1
4          1  0  0
```

```
d1 = dict(list(zip([a[0] for a in valuelabels['S8']], [a[1] for a in valuelabels['S8']])))
print (d1)
{'4': 'Other', '1': 'Medical oncology', '2': 'Hematology', '3': 'Hematology/Oncology'}

d2 = dict(list(zip([a[0] for a in valuelabels['S9']], [a[1] for a in valuelabels['S9']])))
print (d2)
{'1': 'Academic / Teaching Hospital', 
'3': 'Community-Based Group Private Practice (record practice size )', 
'4': 'Community Non-Teaching Hospital', 
'6': 'Other (specify)', 
'2': 'Community-Based Solo Private Practice', 
'5': 'Comprehensive Cancer Center'}
```

```
table = table.reindex(index=[a[0] for a in valuelabels['S8']], 
                      columns=[a[0] for a in valuelabels['S9'], fill_value=0)
print (table)
variable2  1  2  3  4  5  6
variable1                  
1          0  1  0  0  0  0
2          0  0  1  0  0  0
3          0  0  0  0  0  0
4          1  0  0  0  0  0

table.index = table.index.to_series().map(d1).values
table.columns = table.columns.to_series().map(d2).values
```

```
print (table)
                     Academic / Teaching Hospital  \
Medical oncology                                0   
Hematology                                      0   
Hematology/Oncology                             0   
Other                                           1   

                     Community-Based Solo Private Practice  \
Medical oncology                                         1   
Hematology                                               0   
Hematology/Oncology                                      0   
Other                                                    0   

                     Community-Based Group Private Practice (record practice size )  \
Medical oncology                                                     0                
Hematology                                                           1                
Hematology/Oncology                                                  0                
Other                                                                0                

                     Community Non-Teaching Hospital  \
Medical oncology                                   0   
Hematology                                         0   
Hematology/Oncology                                0   
Other                                              0   

                     Comprehensive Cancer Center  Other (specify)  
Medical oncology                               0                0  
Hematology                                     0                0  
Hematology/Oncology                            0                0  
Other                                          0                0
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Glad can help you!

Comment: I am stuck again - now I cannot pass my value labels with pd.crosstab parameters - rownames and colnames. I get `AssertionError: arrays and names must have the same length`. Is there any way of working around that?

Comment: `table = pd.crosstab(df.S8, df.S9)

table = table.reindex(index=[a[0] for a in valuelabels['S8']], columns=[a[0] for a in valuelabels['S9']], fill_value=0)`

I started with this, then tried adding the value label as parameters in pd.crosstab and eventually got that error. If I pass the number of labels that actually exist in my data set everything works fine.

Comment: really interesting. How works crosstab alternative `df = df.pivot_table(index='variable1', columns='variable2', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)` ?

Comment: `valuelabels` is another dataframe?

Comment: If `valuelabels = pd.DataFrame({'S8':pd.Series(['1', '4', '9', '15', '20']), 'S9':pd.Series( ['2', '5', '6'])})` you need `table = pd.crosstab(df.S8, df.S9)` and `table = table.reindex(index=valuelabels['S8'], 
                      columns=valuelabels['S9'], fill_value=0)`

Comment: Sorry need `table = table.reindex(index=valuelabels['S8'], 
                      columns=valuelabels['S9'].dropna(), fill_value=0)`

Comment: valuelables is actually an ordereddict where all the possible values and their labels are stored for all variables. In my list comprehension a[0] returns all the possible codes and a[1] would return all the values.

Comment: `.dropna()` comes up with ~ `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'`. I guess it kind of makes sense since `valuelables['S8']` returns a list of lists - `[['code 1', 'code 1 label], ['code2', 'code 2 label'], ['code3', 'code 3 label'], ['code4', 'code 4 label']]`

I just don't understand what the `dropna()` is supposed to accomplish at this particular case.

Comment: Hmm, it is something like `valuelabels = {'S8':[['1', 'code'],['4', 'code1'],['9', 'code'],['15', 'code1'],['20', 'code']], 
               'S9':[['2', 'code4'],['5', 'code5'],['6', 'code5']]}` ?

Comment: And if use `from collections import OrderedDict` and `valuelabels = OrderedDict({'S8':[['1', 'code'],['4', 'code1'],['9', 'code'],['15', 'code1'],['20', 'code']], 
               'S9':[['2', 'code4'],['5', 'code5'],['6', 'code5']]})` it works also well.

Comment: Not sure if I should be posting this here as it is 'work stuff', but here goes nothing :) `valuelabels` returns `OrderedDict([('S8', [['1', 'Medical oncology'], ['2', 'Hematology'], ['3', 'Hematology/Oncology'], ['4', 'Other']]), ('S9', [['1', 'Academic / Teaching Hospital'], ['2', 'Community-Based Solo Private Practice'], ['3', 'Community-Based Group Private Practice (record practice size )'], ['4', 'Community Non-Teaching Hospital'], ['5', 'Comprehensive Cancer Center'], ['6', 'Other (specify)']])])`

Comment: see my edit, for me it works nice. What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: pandas: 0.19.0, maybe the problem is with how I parse my data:
`reader = csv.DictReader(open(csvinput))

result = {}
for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.items():
        result.setdefault(column, []).append(value)


df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = [key for key in result.keys()])`

Comment: what is `df.info()` and `print (type(df.ix[0,'variable1']))` ? It looks weird if it is standars dataframe.

Comment: variable1 and variable2 were only examples when i started explaining the problem. Now I am trying to cross actual variables named 'S8' and 'S9'.

`df.info()` is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Columns: 196 entries, S9v3 to Q9_4
dtypes: object(196)
memory usage: 76.6+ KB
None`
`print (type(df.ix[0,'S8']))` is `<class 'str'>`

Comment: Yes, and types are `dict` or `list` ?

Comment: Sorry, not following - types of what?

Comment: I keep hitting enter and end up editing my comments so its not your eyes playing tricks on you...

Comment: Are data confidental? Why dont use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) ?

Comment: It is kind of confidential, let me try your option for reading the data.

Comment: Everything is the same with pandas read_csv...

I think the problem is with my codes/labels dict. `print(type(valuelabels['S8']))` returns `<class 'list'>` and the error message is telling me that something is wrong there - `'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'`. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, `dropna` is wrong, because I dont know what is `valuelabels` before. So your solution works nice for me with test data in last edit.

Comment: And one question `AssertionError` return `crosstab` or `reindex` ?

Comment: `crosstab`. It displays the data fine, but what i wanted to do is to display value labels instead of the actual codes for example "Medical oncology" instead of "1", "Hematology" instead of "2" in the downbreak. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use map.

Comment: Give me a sec, I modify solution.

Comment: See my edit. Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dicts`, but need convert `index` to series before by [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html).

Comment: `print(d1)` returns `{'4': 'Other', '2': 'Hematology', '1': 'Medical oncology', '3': 'Hematology/Oncology'}`, but somehow my `print(table)` returns `
     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN    9    4    2    1    1    0
NaN    0    0    0    0    0    0
NaN   33    8   29    8    5    0
NaN    0    0    0    0    0    0`

Comment: Ahh it's all distorted here... The numbers are ok, but for some reason I get NaN instead of labels.

Comment: are keys in dicts strings? And `table.index` is string also? (`Index(['1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype='object', name='variable1')`). Or both types are `int` ?

Comment: Keys in dicts are strings, but `print(type(table.index))` yields `<class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Float64Index'>`

Comment: so need cast `index` to `str`, but before to `int` - `df.index = df.index.astype(int).astype(str)`.

Comment: I've added `table.index = table.index.astype(int).astype(str)
table.columns = table.columns.astype(int).astype(str)` as it seemed I needed it for both the index and columns and it finally works! thanks a lot for your patience and time!

Answer (score 4):

You can use reindex:

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df.variable1, df.variable2)
ct.reindex(index=variable1, columns=variable2).fillna(0).astype('int')
Out: 
variable2  2  5  6
variable1         
1          1  0  0
4          0  0  0
9          1  0  0
15         0  0  0
20         0  0  1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def TargetPercentByNominal (
 targetVar,       # target variable
 predictor):      # nominal predictor

countTable = pandas.crosstab(index = predictor, columns = targetVar, margins = True, dropna = True)
  x = countTable.drop('All', 1)
  percentTable = countTable.div(x.sum(1), axis='index')*100

  print("Frequency Table: \n")
  print(countTable)
  print( )
  print("Percent Table: \n")
  print(percentTable)

  return
```

Comment: Don't just post code - please explain the motivations behind it